# Does SharePoint come with Windows Server?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, licensing

I am working on a justification to buy SharePoint 2010. One of the points I want to make is that my corporation already owns it! Can I say that "SharePoint ships with Microsoft’s Windows Server software"? I am a writer relying on people to provide me information and can't seem to get a straight answer on this. I thought I could find it online but I am more confused than ever.

Please advise

Comment: Corrected those tags for you

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.

If you have Windows Server then SharePoint Foundation Include in it. SharePoint Foundation is free /lite version of SharePoint server.
SharePoint Foundation 2010 is a versatile technology that organizations and business units of all sizes can use to increase the efficiency of business processes and improve team productivity. With tools for collaboration that help people stay connected across organizational and geographic boundaries, SharePoint Foundation 2010 gives people access to information they need.

[SharePoint Foundation 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288070(v=office.14).aspx) and One more thing SharePoint Foundation license is covered under the Windows Server Cal, that's mean if a user covered under the Windows Server then he covered under SPF.

[SharePoint Server 2010.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303422(v=office.14).aspx) Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 is the business collaboration platform for the enterprise. Use SharePoint Server 2010 to connect people with colleagues and information; manage and govern enterprise content; balance user experience with policy and process; and help users find the content, information, and people they need with enterprise search.

SharePoint Server product, you have to buy separate license according to your need either Standard & Enterprise.

Comment: thank you. I find it tough to understand how Microsoft licenses their products. I find that a seemingly simple question often results in a "yes but no" answer. You have done a great job breaking it down for me and I appreciate it.